# How can I hide a button in "new row" template in WPF Data Grid?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, datagrid

I have a grid having images and buttons to allow the user to add or del the images. Example:

[image: Example]

Both button visibility are binded to the model. **Xaml:**

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Photo" IsReadOnly="True">
<DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Button Name="btnAddPhoto" Content=" Add " Visibility="{Binding BtnAddPhotoVisibility}"></Button>
            <Button Name="BtnExcludePhoto" Content=" Del " Visibility="{Binding BtnExcludePhotoVisibility}"></Button>
            <Image  MaxHeight="50" MaxWidth="50" Tag="Photo" Stretch="Uniform" Source="{Binding Photo}" MouseUp="OnMouseUpBinary" />
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
```

And here is model code having the visibility logic for "DEL" button. "ADD" button is similar.

```
public Visibility BtnExcludePhotoVisibility
{
    get
    {
        if ((this.Photo == null) || (this.Photo.Length == 0))
            return Visibility.Collapsed;
        else
            return Visibility.Visible;
    }
    set { _BtnExcludePhotoVisibility = value; }
}
```

The problem is: last row (used to add itens) is in the grid but not really binded **when open the grid**, (like the image). If I click in last row, the class in list is created and the logic that manipulates the control visibility is triggered. After editing the last row, this happens:

[image]

The question is: **How trigger the visibility logic for DEL button in last row when opening the grid?**

Comment: Looks like you are missing notifications for bindings (to hide `Add` button and show `Del`). Google for `INotifyPropertyChanged` and in general read about MVVM.

Comment: I din't missed, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set the `Fallback` property of the binding to `Collapsed`:

```
<Button Name="BtnExcludePhoto" Content=" Del "
    Visibility="{Binding BtnExcludePhotoVisibility, FallbackValue=Collapsed}" />
```

This should collapse it by default when the binding cannot be resolved.

Comment: Thanks, Mister, this solved the problem. God bless you and your family.

Answer (score 0):

I think the you have a NullReferenceExeption in your Binding.

```
(this.Photo == null) || (this.Photo.Length == 0)
```

if the Photo is null this.Photo.Length == 0 raises a NullRefereneExeption.

Do  this.Photo?.Length == 0 or classic :

```
if (this.Photo == null) 
     return Visibility.Collapsed;
else
  if this.Photo.Lenght == 0
    return Visibility.Collapsed;


....
```

Comment: Did not worked, but thanks Sven. Debuging the code, the getter is triggered 3 times: for ids 8,9  and 10. The last row don't hit the getter because the counterpart class in the list don't exist. That means: grid have 4 rows, but the list have 3 itens. The last item in grid exists only visually, not in the observable collection. When last row gets in edit mode, the 4th class is include, triggering the getter.